# onTouch Method to Work Once Per Touch

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I make a 2d game. When I touch a column , 2 or 3 cell is changing, not 1.

If I keep touch on the screen, onTouch method work until I lift my finger.
But ı don't want this, I Want onTouch method to work once per touch.
How can I do this?

This is a part of my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer);
    MyView a = new MyView(this);
    setContentView(a);


    a.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            float mX = motionEvent.getX();

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                    if (board[0][j].getterCellType() == '.') {
                        if (mX > board[i][j].getterxPos()-50 && mX < board[i][j].getterxPos() + 50) {
                            playColumn = board[i][j].getterColumn();
                            play();
                            return true;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Could you provide the code?

Comment: Probable Solution:  return true from onTouch() method

Comment: @SantiagoSalem I edited

Comment: @KoushikShomChoudhury I already return true see my edited post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to only execute once, then you shoud detect `ACTION_DOWN`. The `onTouch` method will be called in every `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`, `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`, and `MotionEvent.UP`.

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
       //code code code
    }
}
```